# Setting Client_Secret white fetching tokens using ForgeRock Javascript SDK

Tags: openam, forgerock

I am trying to fetch tokens after completing an authentication flow (username and password based) using OpenAM central login. In my callback url, I receive the auth code and state, which in turn I should call the `getTokens` function available in the ForgeRock javascript sdk.
I am referring the code given [here](https://github.com/ForgeRock/forgerock-javascript-sdk/blob/develop/packages/javascript-sdk/src/token-manager/index.ts#L61), the expected response is a JWT, but the resulting response is `Error: invalid_client: Client authentication failed`.

In my ForgeRock config options, I can see that I can enter my OAuth2 Client ID, but can't see any field which accepts client secret, due to which authentication is failing.

Is there a way to setup client secret? Or another workaround which doesn't require client secret and just the auth code and state would suffice to fetch JWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given error `Error: invalid_client: Client authentication failed` also comes when the auth code issued by the provider (OpenAM in this case) has expired.

By default, the expiration of the code is Zero, I had to manually increase the timeout and it worked.